# Rails error ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#65709220) expected, got String(#19934580)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

Hi um using rspec in rails and um creating a valid user as follows

```
it "should create a valid user" do
    @user = User.find_or_create_machine_user("test@dllo.no","test_first",     "test_last").should be_an_instance_of User
  end
```

this test passes and works fine , but when I include this section um getting an error

```
 @batch = FactoryGirl.create(:batch, :file_name => "test_file",
                                  :created_by=> @user)
```

and says `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       User(#65709220) expected, got String(#19934580)` . I tried with created_by_id = @user.id.to_int this also got failed.

schema

```
class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :created_by
  attr_accessible :created_by, :file_name
```

Can anyone tell how to overcome from this? created_by accepts a user

Comment: It would help if you could share your entire spec and the specific error you got when you used `@user.id.to_int` instead.

Comment: and your related model/schema so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: What's the definition of `User.find_or_create_machine_user`?

Comment: it will create a valid user :) that function works fine and returns a user object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spec is assigning the value of the assertion to @user.  @user is thus not a User.  Also, `find_or_create_machine_user` looks pretty strange.  You should use a variation of `find_or_create_by` or better yet write a factory for User.  Passing this actual instance of User class should solve the issue.

```
it "should create a valid user" do
  @user = User.find_or_create_machine_user("test@dllo.no","test_first","test_last")
  @user.should be_an_instance_of User
end
```

Comment: I passed an actual user class tnen it says user required came a string